# Chart.js to PHPWord

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js, phpword

Is it possible to capture a canvas that has chart on it to phpword file? I just read this [Add chart on phpoffice/phpword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941382/add-chart-on-phpoffice-phpword) and it said it still not possible. even it's possible like this https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_32_Chart.php , it's still limited and I need my chart that has generated by my javascript and chart.js. I tried use filesaver.js but it just saved canvas to image, not pass it to controller (I'm using codeigniter). Any idea how to do it? Or is it still not possible?

Comment: Savd your chart as image and then use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_13_Images.php. You don't need the charting funtionalities, since you've created the chart already. But you will need to take care of resolution and readability. Otherwise you would need to pass all your raw data and then use the charting options of PHPWord.

Comment: I understand that we can insert image in phpword, but how to insert the chart automatically after it displayed as picture on the page? the idea of right click, save chart as image, and insert it manually on the code doesn't sound right. @mistapink

Comment: Either you know from your code when picture has been drawn or you create some kind of event listener on the canvas. Then create a base64 encoded blob from the canvas ‘toDataURL()’, send it via XHR to PHP. Depending on if PHP Word can just embed pictures from the disk you might need to store the file temporary and then pass the location to PHP Word.

Comment: the problem is from what I know toDataUrl store the image as blob, and phpword can't read it. so the picture must be convert to png or jpg file first. I still can't find how to do it. maybe any suggestion about it? thanks. @mistapink

Comment: Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL. Take the returned string, pass it via POST to PHP, store the image temporary and use it. Since you haven't showed any code of what you tried, it is hard to help you. The recipe has been given in this and my last comment.